# How to round a decimal number to whole number in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, math

Let's say the decimal numbers are 1.12, 8.23, 2.35, 9.44 & 5.14
What I want is I want to round all the numbers whose decimal is less than 0.3 to the lesser whole number and the remaining to the greater whole number.

For example

1.12 would become 1

8.23 would become 8

2.35 would become 3

9.44 would become 10

5.14 would become 5

How do I do that? Please help

Answer (score 0):

This function rounds based on the difference between a double and its absolute value.

1.2 -> 1

1.4 -> 2

```
private int round(double d){
    double dAbs = Math.abs(d);
    int i = (int) dAbs;
    double result = dAbs - (double) i;
    if(result<0.3){ //you can change this value
        return d<0 ? -i : i;            
    }else{
        return d<0 ? -(i+1) : i+1;          
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using BigDecimal, since it is more precision to process decimal number.

> Might be not relate of your case, but still useful about decimal processing. https://dzone.com/articles/never-use-float-and-double-for-monetary-calculatio

```
private long customRound(Double value) {
        BigDecimal bigDecimalNumber = BigDecimal.valueOf(value);
        Integer intValue = bigDecimalNumber.intValue();
        BigDecimal decimalValue = bigDecimalNumber.subtract(BigDecimal.valueOf(intValue));

        if (decimalValue.compareTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.3)) > 0.3) {
            return intValue + 1;
        }
        return intValue;
    }
```

This way we are trying to separate between the absolute number and decimal one. Then, we validate that the decimal is more than 0.3 or not.